# how correctly get country and other info from sql for specific id

Tags: php, sql, post, get

I am trying to get country and other info from sql for specific id,  only  "`id`" displays correctly in both cases.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `list`  ORDER BY category ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $country = $_GET['country'];

    echo $id;
    echo $country;  
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `list`  ORDER BY category ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $country = $_GET['country'];

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $id;
    echo $country;  
    }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: you mean you have the Country name, and you want to get its record?
please specify more

Comment: Your line `$id = $_GET['id'];` is setting the `$id` variable from a value passed in the URL string, not from the database - is this intentional?

Comment: yes, id passed from url, but how get country from sql (dagta base) for this id

Comment: Can you show us an example of your desired output?

Comment: if you're looking to use a specific id/country, then you need to use a `WHERE` clause. Your GET arrays should be used in conjunction with your query. Your code doesn't do much here really.

Comment: `$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` and `while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` also doesn't do much here neither.

Comment: i try use $sql = "SELECT * FROM `list`  WHERE `country` ='".$country."'" ORDER BY category ASC";

Comment: place your GET arrays "above" your query. You're putting the wagon before the horse here.

Comment: sorry, maybe I do something wrong, are new in PHP , you can show me how should look this ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a column named id and another named country from which you want to collect the data in the country row of a certain record.
I have similar ideas to some of the comments and would like to highlight my thoughts in this answer.

1. $_GET superglobal is used to extract data form a URL parameter. If it is used to get the data from the record, you might want to use mysql_fetch_assoc($result)["country"]. For more information, please take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
   and https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_get.asp
2. To filter certain records according to some input id, you would want to use the WHERE clause. Link for more information:- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp
   The possible code might be:-

```php
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"]
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `list` WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY category ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $rows['id'];
        echo $rows['country'];  
    }
} 
?>
```

PS: I have tried my best to answer the asked question provided the less information given. Hope it helps

Comment: @Max, please let me know if the solution works. Awaiting your reply.